# Fabric.js stage.getActiveObject().clone() vs. fabric.util.object.clone(stage.getActiveObject())

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clone, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric.js and I'm trying to implement a copy function for images and text element. I found two solutions for on how to copy objects:

Method 1

```
stage.getActiveObject().clone();
```

Method 2

```
fabric.util.object.clone(stage.getActiveObject());
```

When using the first method, the cloning won't occur, when using the second method the cloning does occur. To be more specific, for the first method I used the following code:

```
var obj = stage.getActiveObject();
if (!obj) return;

var clone = obj.clone();
clone.set({
    top: clone.get('top') + 30
});
stage.add(clone);
stage.renderAll();
```

When running this code on an active object it keeps telling that clone is undefined. Although both methods would do the same thing there must a good reason for using either method 1 or 2.

Could anyone explain the difference between those 2?

Another thing I noticed is that when using the 2nd method, `fabric.util.object.clone(stage.getActiveObject());` the cloned object gets the same ID as the original object. Although cloning makes a clone of the original I wouldn't make sense to me that they share the same ID. In other words, how can I clone an object and give it a unique ID?

Comment: You can see in the docs that `fabric.Object#clone()` (#1) is asynchronous — http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#clone That's why your `clone` is undefined. Any time you clone Fabric object, you should be using `.clone()` (#1). `util.clone` is just a simple cloning utility that could be used with other, non-Fabric objects.

Comment: Hey kangax, thanks for replying. It's still a bit unclear to me why the clone is undefined. I am using obj.clone() in my code example. I might be missing just a simple step, could you be more specific? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: clone is passed into a callback function, since it's asynchronous

Comment: This sounds like a conceptual flaw to me. The `clone()` method is invoked on an in-memory representation, there's no need to trigger asynchronous reconstitution to fetch resources like SVGs or images over the network. Thus, fabric.js should not invoke the `fromObject()` method on cloning, but a dedicated (blocking) method.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so I figured out a solution for my issue. It works for me so maybe it can help others. This is my final code that does what I'm after.:

```
var object = fabric.util.object.clone(stage.getActiveObject());
stage.discardActiveObject();

object.title = object.title + '_copy';
object.id = (object.id * 2);
object.set("top", object.top+20);
object.set("left", object.left+20);

stage.add(object);
stage.renderAll();
```

I need a unique ID per object for my application so I'm multiplying the original ID by 2. Still, if someone has a better solution or can give me more info on why Method 1 from my post above didnt work feel free to leave a note.